# How to convert mm/dd/yy to yy/mm/dd using pandas in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, date

I have a data table which consists of various columns including a date field which is in the form of (mm/dd/yy) as follows:
[image]

Now, how can I have to convert it to (yy/mm/dd) format?

I have used the following code:

```
d['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(d['Date'], format='%m/%d/%y')
```

But I am getting an error as follows:

```
ValueError: unconverted data remains: 05
```

Can someone please help me out with this? I know its relatively basic, but I am not able to get it.

Answer (score 3):

I think there are some another format data, you can change them to `NaT`:

```
#check them
print (d[pd.to_datetime(d['Date'], format='%m/%d/%y', errors='coerce').isna()])

d['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(d['Date'], format='%m/%d/%y', errors='coerce')
```